# How do I create a Distribution Managed certificate in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, app-store-connect

I have a cert that expires in 2 days that says its type is "Distribution Managed". I've tried following the documentation to recreate this same cert and have only been able to create a "Distribution" cert.

Is "Distribution Managed" a legacy cert-type or something? I can't find any info about this on StackOverflow or anywhere else. Seems to be a very cryptic part of the app dev process...

I create a new cert using the tools on App Store Connect, and uploading a CSR generated from my computer to create the cert. I expected it to make a cert with a different name, but the same cert type and a later expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the "Managed -" certificate types are certs that are auto-generated and renewed (managed) by Xcode and/or the other platforms that Apple manages.

The "creator" seems to be grabbed from the developer that runs an archive and selects "managed" signing certificates during the process.